# Currying with setTimeout - JS

Tags: javascript, prototype, settimeout, currying

I want to create a method for the `Function prototype` that will add a `setTimeout` automatically. I got it with this:

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function (delay) {
  setTimeout(this, delay);
};
    
function f() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}
    
f.defer(1000);
```

And now I need to pass parameters to my function with currying like this:

```
function f(a, b) {
  console.log( a + b );
}

f.defer(1000)(4, 2);
```

And I achieved it with just currying but not with `setTimeout`:

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function (delay) {
  return this
};

function f(a,b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

f.defer(1000)(4, 2);
```

But when I try to add the `setTimeout` it loses its **this** or didn't recognize it as a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return another function that will capture and pass arguments.

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function (delay) {
  return (...args) => setTimeout(this, delay, ...args)
};

function f(a,b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

f.defer(1000)(4, 2);
console.log('test')
```

Or using `bind`

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function (delay) {
  return setTimeout.bind(null, this, delay)
};

function f(a,b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

f.defer(2000)(4, 2);
console.log('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a modification to your `.defer()` function:

```js
    Function.prototype.defer = function (delay, ... args) {
      setTimeout(this.bind(undefined, ... args), delay);
    };
        
    function f(a, b) {
      console.log("a + b is " + (a + b));
    }
    
    f.defer(2000, 4, 5);
```